# How do I get an index from an array in PHP?

Tags: php

I a code like this

```
for($ctr=0; $ctr < 4; $ctr++) {
    $messages["message"] = $ctr;
    array_push($response["messages"], $messages);
}
```

I want to get the `message` that contains the value `2`. How do I do that in PHP?

Answer (score 1):

```
for($ctr=0; $ctr < 4; $ctr++) {
    $messages["message"] = $ctr;
    array_push($response["messages"], $messages);
}

function mysearch($val) {
    global $response;
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($response["messages"]); $i++) {
        if ($response["messages"][$i]["message"] === $val) {
            return $i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}

echo mysearch(2); // will print the index, or -1 if not found
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to use array search on this case.

```
for($ctr=0; $ctr < 4; $ctr++) {
    //$messages["message"] = $ctr;
    array_push($response, $ctr);
}
echo array_search('2', $response);
```

array search give you the index of the array which value is 2.

Comment: except that there's no value '2' in $response (unless he added it before the code that he posted:)

Comment: Actually i just answer the question without debugging the code for bugs.
i see the question and give answer. Thanks for your attention on it.@Gavriel

Comment: maybe, but that's probably not his intention, at least from the code he posted (though, it might be that OP didn't know how to write what he wants)

Comment: Actually, I need something like this. `message[] = {"0", "1", "2", "3"}` and to get the value `0` from message I use `message[0]`. Sorry, I don't know much PHP that's why I don't know how do I use something equivalent to this.